# What minor modification author ask us to do to get $df(p)(v_p) = Df(p)(v)$?

Tags: calculus, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This is from Calculus in Manifold by Michael Spivak Chapter 4 Integration on Chains.
If $f: Rn -> R$ is differentiate, then $Df(p)\in \wedge^1(R^n)$. By a 
minor modification we therefore obtain a 1-form $df$, defined by 
$df(p)(v_p) = Df(p)(v)$. 
Let us consider in particular the 1-forms $d\pi^i$. It is customary 
to let $x^i$ denote the function $\pi^i$(On $R^3$ we often denote 
$x^1$, $x^2$ and $x^3$ by $x$, $y$, and $z$.) This standard notation has 
obvious disadvantages but it allows many classical results 
to be expressed by formulas of equally classical appearance. 
Since $dx^i(p)(v_p) = d\pi^i(p)(v_p) = D\pi^i(p)(v) = v^i$, we see that 
$dx^1(p), . . . ,dx^n(p)$ is just the dual basis to $(e_1)_p, . . . ,(e_n)_p$. 
Thus every $k-form$ $\omega$ can be written 
$\omega=\sum_{i_1<...<i_k} \omega_{i_1}..._{i_k}dx^{i_1}\wedge..\wedge dx^{i_k}$

This is my first Question  here.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the domain of $df(p)$ is the tangent space at p (thus typical input being $v_p$) while that of $Df(p)$ is plain $\mathbb{R}^n$. This modification Spivak asks you to notice.

What is the significance of such trick?
In $\mathbb{R}^n$ there is so natural an isomorphism between the tangent space at each point and $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself that $df$ and $Df$ look almost the same. But when you deal with wider class of spaces, you don't have such pleasing identification in general. Imagine how you would define a differential on a curved space like $S^n$!

To do calculus on such spaces(which is the author's goal as the title of the book suggests) you really need the notion of tangent space and must define differential forms in terms of it.

Comment: one more thing,i know here $x^i$ denotes the function $\pi^i$,so $x^i(v)=v^i$,the $i^{th} $component  of v.But in some places i saw the function $dx^i$ also defined as the same.So why both are defined same way?

Comment: That question can also be answered in the same spirit. For the general class of manifolds, which contains but is far larger than the class of Euclidean spaces, $x^i$ denotes a local coordinate system on a manifold. This coordinate map need not be linear; the space may be curved! But to understand such spaces("manifolds") it is extremely useful to locally approximate the given curved space $M$ with flat Euclidean spaces. These flat spaces attached at each point of $M$ we call "tangent spaces".

Comment: Furthermore the differentiable functions defined on $M$ may be understood via their 'linear approximations', namely the differential forms such as $dx^i$ defined on tangent spaces. But since the linear approximation of a linear function is the function itself, taking the differential of $x^i$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ changes nothing. This need not be true on manifolds in general. So the coincidence you pointed out is a characteristic property of $\mathbb{R}^n$. It doesn't mean things like $dx^i$ are useless; they really matter when you deal with curved spaces!

Comment: and Why $Df(p) \in \wedge^1(R^n)$,I mean why this function is guaranteed to be alternating if f is differentiable?